# Como referenciar o userID e emitir uma notificação no firebase

Tags: firebase, realtime-database

Eu estou tendo a seguinte estrutura do real time database:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E estou tentando criar um gatilho para que sempre que uma mensagem for adicionada no user003 eu envie uma notificação através do FCM minha função não está funcionando

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.fcmSend = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {

  console.log('event', event)

  const message = event.after.val()
  const userId  = event.params.userId
  const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: message.title,
          body: message.body,
          icon: "https://placeimg.com/250/250/people"
        }
      };


   admin.database()
        .ref(`/fcmTokens/${userId}`)
        .once('value')
        .then(token => token.val() )
        .then(userFcmToken => {
          return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFcmToken, payload)
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Sent Successfully", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('err', err);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu mudaria estas linhas aqui, da uma olhada no log as mensagens

return admin.database()
        .ref(`/fcmTokens/${userId}`)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log("token", snapshot.val() );
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload)
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log("Sent Successfully", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err', err);
        });